# Question about the What's In the Box code game assignment

Tags: pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I am struggling to understand how to properly use pass by value and reference in this program. It keeps saying identifier is undefined when I put the Int in the main function. But when it's out of the main function it works fine. I can't use it outside of the main function otherwise it's an automatic 0. Am I just missing code that identifies it?

I didn't explain the program very well. It's essentially the Monty Hall problem but with boxes. The user then tries to guess the right box. The biggest issue I had was getting the non prize box to appear to the user in the output.

I am very new to coding so I am probably overlooking something.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <iomanip>

#include <iostream>

#include <time.h>

#include <string>

using namespace std;
```

/*******************************************************************************
*  Function Name: main()
*  Parameters: None
*  Return Value: int
*  Purpose: To execute the main function of the program. Performs loops and takes user input to execute the game.
*****************************************************************************/

```
void BoxCheck(int);

void PrizeBox(int&);

//int UserGuess = 0;






int main()
{

    int UserChoice;

    int UserGuess;

    int BoxReveal;

    int PrizeB;

   // int Prize;

   //char Switch;


   cout << "Wellcome to Pandora's Prize!" << endl;

   cout << "Infront of you there are three doors, and behind one of them is the grand prize!" << endl;

   cout << "But in the the other two they contain a stink bomb." << endl;

   cout << "It's your job to guess which one has the prize behind it." << endl;

   cout << "Door 1?" << endl;

   cout << "Door 2?" << endl;

   cout << "Door 3?" << endl;

   PrizeBox(PrizeB);


   cin >> UserGuess;

   BoxReveal != (PrizeB || UserGuess);



    // cout << "The host revealed box number " << BoxReveal << " ." << endl;
    //if (true)
    //{
    if (UserGuess == 1)
    {
        cout << "You picked box 1." << endl;



        cout << "The host revealed box number " << BoxReveal << " ." << endl;



        cout << "Would you like to stay with box number 1 or switch." << endl;



        //cin >> UserChoice;

    }

    else if (UserGuess == 2)
    {
       cout << "You picked box 2." << endl;



        cout << "The host revealed box number " << BoxReveal << " ." << endl;



        cout << "Would you like to stay with box number 2 or switch." << endl;



        //cin >> UserChoice;

    }

    else if (UserGuess == 3)
    {
        cout << "You picked box 3." << endl;



        cout << "The host revealed box number " << BoxReveal << " ." << endl;

        cout << "It contains a red snapper!" << endl;

        cout << "Would you like to stay with box number 3 or switch." << endl;

        //cin >> UserChoice;


    }

    else
    {

        cout << "This isn't a number associated with a box. Try again." << endl;



    }

    //}

    /* if (true)
    {

    } */


    //PrizeBox(Prize);
    if (UserChoice == UserGuess)
    {
        cout << "You chose to stay with your original box." << endl;

        BoxCheck(UserGuess);
    }



    else if (UserChoice != UserGuess)  //|| UserChoice != BoxReveal)
    {
        cout << "You decided to switch." << endl;

        BoxCheck(UserGuess);
    }



     /*else if (UserChoice != UserGuess || BoxReveal)
    {
        cout << "You decided to switch." << endl;

        BoxCheck(UserGuess);
    } */

    else
    {
        cout << "Your answer was out of the parameters." << endl;

        BoxCheck(UserGuess);
    } 


    //BoxCheck(UserGuess);

    system("pause");

    return 0;

}



void PrizeBox(int& PrizeB)
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    PrizeB = rand() % 3 + 1;

    //Prize = rand() % 3 + 1;

    //cin >> PrizeB;

    /* BoxReveal = !(PrizeBox || boxChoice);
    cout << "Here is one of the box's opened! " << boxReveal << " ." << endl;
    BSwitch = (boxChoice || boxReveal); */




}


void BoxCheck(int UserChoice)
{
    if (UserChoice == PrizeB)
    {
        cout << "WOW YOU WON!!!!" << endl;
    }

    else if (UserChoice != PrizeB)
    {
        cout << "Sorry you got a red snapper" << endl;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "Sorry you got a red snapper" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you link us to the problem at least, or better yet include the relevant bits in the question here? I haven't heard of it. Can you show us your best attempt at the code and the error it's giving you (the 'identifier is undefined' one?)

Comment: `BoxReveal != (PrizeB || UserGuess);` This doesn't look right. I guess you're trying to pick either the number between 1 and 3 that is neither PrizeB nor UserGuess if they're different, or a random other alternative if they're the same? `!=` is a comparison, and won't update BoxReveal.

Comment: Also PrizeB is a variable in the main() function, so BoxCheck won't have access to the value unless you pass it in there too as an argument. (You could also make PrizeB a global variable in the file, but that's not good style IMO.)

Comment: "The biggest issue I had was getting the non prize box to appear to the user in the output." - yes, as I said your `BoxReveal != (PrizeB || UserGuess);` line doesn't actually do anything. You'll need to write more code to generate the right value for BoxReveal.

Comment: @Rup For some reason I can't figure out how to pass it as an argument. I'm guessing that calling the pass by reference again is not what you mean.

Comment: Passing PrizeB to BoxCheck? No, BoxCheck just needs the value. Make it a second parameter, i.e. `void BoxCheck(int,int);`, call it as `BoxCheck(UserGuess, PrizeB);` and make the implementation `void BoxCheck(int UserChoice, int PrizeB) {`

Comment: @Rup I still can't figure out how to update BoxReveal. Should I do it in multiple equations? Or do I use a different comparison for it altogether? It would be nice if I could have it not equal those two variables and by 1-3 like you pointed out.

Comment: I can't think of a great way. You can e.g. create a `set<int>` or `vector<int>` and add 1, 2 and 3 to it; then remove PrizeB, then remove UserGuess. Depending on whether PrizeB == UserGuess or not you'll have either one or two elements left in the set or vector. If it's one, BoxReveal = that element. If it's two, choose a random number 0 or 1 then take that index element from the vector or set.

Comment: Or there are few enough permutations here you can do it with ifs, e.g. `if (PrizeB != UserGuess) {` `if ((PrizeB == 1 && UserGuest == 2) || (PrizeB == 2 && UserGuest == 1) { BoxReveal = 3; }` `else { ... } }` `else { ... }` Which isn't very nice but will do the job without allocation, so you could argue that's the better way. But it's certainly less readable and clear.

Comment: @Rup I thought of trying that but I got lost trying to figure out how to fix all the possible choices. For example if the user guess is 1 and the PrizeB happens to also be 1. I couldn't figure out how to factor that all in. But you mean have multiple if statements inside each other?

Comment: Another maybe easier way: set BoxReveal to a random number 1-3. If it = PrizeB or = UserGuess, pick another random number and repeat until it doesn’t equal either or them.

Comment: @Rup How do you come up with different ways to do it so quickly? I seem to struggle with thinking more then one way. Either way I appreciate all the help....this stuff gets a bit overwhelming for me.